# How to bind 2 textures correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glsl

I'm newbie in OpenGL and trying to get color difference between 2 textures. 
It's my init function:

```
glGenTextures(1, &TEX0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEX0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);


glGenTextures(1, &TEX1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEX1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, MODE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, MODE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER1);
```

It's my display func:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glUseProgram(shader);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEX0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEX1);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "tex0"), 0);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "tex1"), 1);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(-1,-1);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(-1,+1);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(+1,+1);
glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(+1,-1);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glUseProgram(0);
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

And it's my fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;

void main()
{
    vec4 otex = texture2D(oframe, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 ntex = texture2D(nframe, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(otex.rgb - ntex.rgb), 1.0);
}
```

So the problem is the first activated texture always black. How to solve this?
There are a lot of similar topics, but none of them helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

First mistake: OpenGL is a state machine. The call of glTexImage effects on the currently bound texture in the currently selective texture unit. You must write it this way:

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, MODE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glGenTextures(1, &tex1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, MODE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

It doesn't really matter if glTexImage comes before or after glTexParameter of glTexEnv, it works either way. Since you're using a fragment shader glTexEnv is unneccesary. Everything glTexEnv could set has been replaced by the versatility of an expression in a fragment shader.